# Calculate mean with Numpy base on other column values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data set containing the following:

[Table Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4HXX0.png)

And I need to calculate the mean of the duration column only for Jan and Conditions Yes. I tried this but it is not giving the correct value

```
Jan_Mean = np.where((df['Date']=="Jan")  & (df['Condition']=="Yes"), df["Duration"],0).mean()
```

Comment: I think you want `Jan_Mean = np.where((df['Date']=="Jan")  & (df['Condition']=="Yes"), df["Duration"].mean() ,0)`

Comment: Welcome to SO!, although this is a small example, for future reference I recommend checking [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) on posting `pandas` related questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pandas uses NumPy under the hood, something like

```
df[(df['Date']=="Jan")  & (df['Condition']=="Yes")]["Duration"].mean()
```

should do the trick. Here

```
(df['Date']=="Jan")  & (df['Condition']=="Yes")
```

is a boolean mask, so applied to the dataframe you get a filtered version of it, then accessing to the column you can use its methods. More available methods [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.html).

Answer (score 1):

```
df.groupby(['Date','Condition']).mean().loc['Jan','Yes'][0]

Out[1]:
1.5
```

#### Explanation

This gives you the desired data in DataFrame format:

```
df.groupby(['Date','Condition']).mean()
Out[2]:

                Duration
Date    Condition   
Feb     Yes     3.0
Jan     Yes     1.5
```

Comment: Not exactly what I needed but it can definitely help in the future. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

How about using a groupby and mean.

```
df.groupby(['Date', 'Condition']).mean().loc[('Jan', 'Yes')]
```